# Battery Maintainers

Tags: batteries, storage, conditioning

I have a bunch of non-rechargeable batteries I've kept in stock & haven't used almost at all (almost fresh off the packaging). Like all tools/equipment I have, I expect them to last me as long as I live. Because I typically opt for my rechargeable batteries anyways.

Therefore my non-rechargeables can last. That is, if it weren't for self-discharge...

So I have this idea of "Battery Maintainers" (just because the name "battery conditioners" is already taken).

The idea is this:

Mint fresh batteries are typically a little above the advertised voltage (nominal voltage). These fresh batteries will then be connected to a power supply that is **exactly** this nominal voltage, with the supply's cathode going to each batteries' anode via a diode.

Because of the individual diode, the batteries with slightly higher voltage won't go on to charge the lower voltaged batteries. If the battery still has not fallen to nominal, then no harm done. If a battery leaks & start to smidge be lower than nominal value, very, very low current will go flow through the diode as small signal regime (< 0.7V, silicon diode), charging it back up very gently.

There are rechargeable alkalines, but whether in general non-rechargeable (carbon-zinc & alkaline) chemistries allows for a "smidge" of charging is something I don't know for sure.

Would this work as a battery storage solution?

Comment: That’s exactly how our residential chemist did back when I worked for a company making battery charges to his alkaline batteries when not in use to maintain them from self-discharge. I find them too cheap and widely available to bother.